# What is the best solution for migrating Linq DBML tables?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, version-control, data-migration

I'm trying to figure out the best way to deal with database updates with Linq. I'd like a clean way to checking database changes. I'd like to use a ruby style migration scripts, but I'd also like to keep everything in sync with the DBML file. What is the best way to do this? Do I need to write a custom solution to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean changes in schema? If so, a custom code generator is certainly one option and a better one than manually updating the DBMLs every time schema changes. But there are third party tools out there to sync schema changes, as well:

http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/

if you are willing to go away from LINQ as a data access model, there are OR/M tools, or OR/M like tools, that give you control over code generation.